# Package development: R CMD Check cannot find R package (no namespace error) used in Rcpp function

Tags: rcpp, r-package

I have an R package where I have written some functions in Rcpp. In a new function, I am using the `fastglm` package in Rcpp using this code:

```
double estAUC(NumericMatrix dmatrix, NumericVector y) {
  .
  .
  .

  Environment pkg = Environment::namespace_env("fastglm");
  Function f = pkg["fastglm"];
  Function p = pkg["predict.fastglm"];

  List fit = f(Named("x", dmatrix), Named("y", y));
  NumericVector pred = p(Named("object", fit), Named("newdata", dmatrix));

  .
  .
  .
```

The function works very well. I have also written tests that call the function, which all pass. However, when I run R CMD Check, I get the following error.

```
Running the tests in ‘tests/testthat.R’ failed.
   Last 13 lines of output:
      4.   └─base::loadNamespace(name)
      5.     └─base::withRestarts(stop(cond), retry_loadNamespace = function() NULL)
      6.       └─base (local) withOneRestart(expr, restarts[[1L]])
      7.         └─base (local) doWithOneRestart(return(expr), restart)
     ── Error ('test-utility.R:184:3'): logisticCoefs works. ────────────────────────
     <Rcpp::no_such_namespace/C++Error/error/condition>
     Error: No such namespace: fastglm.
     Backtrace:
         ▆
      1. └─simstudy::logisticCoefs(d1, coefs, popPrev = tPop, auc = auc) at test-utility.R:184:2
      2.   └─simstudy:::getBeta_auc(...)
```

I have included `fastglm` in the *LinkingTo* block of the Descriptions file, and I tried adding `// [[Rcpp::depends(fastglm)]]`, but that did not solve the problem. If I add `fastglm` to the *Imports* block of Descriptions, I do not get the error message, but I get a note indicating that `fastglm` has been imported but is not being used.

Is there a correct way I should be handling this?

Comment: Hi -- can you post a link to your repo, based on the incomplete info it is hard to say anything.  I would probably go with the `Imports: fastglm` (which makes sure symbols are loaded) and just by-convenience import one other function to quieten `R CMD check`.  (And none of this Rcpp-specific, really.  More of a generic packaging question.)

Comment: Thanks - I figured that was a solution, but seemed kind of like cheating. My repo is https://github.com/kgoldfeld/simstudy, and the branch is issue-126-simulate-for-auc.

Comment: Thanks, I did find the repo via the mirror at github.com/cran/ but the package is a wee bit large for me to "just dive in" for a quick tip.  I think the long and the short of it is that you you need an import for R to resolve symbols, just how we say your Rcpp-using package should have, say, `importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)` to set things up.  R does a few things behind the scenes, and it is best to play along.  Come to the rcpp-devel list for more help if you need it.